# Java SWT updating canvas from another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, canvas, swt

I'm developing a Java application that does basically:

- Starts a server in a new thread. This server opens a socket connection and waits for messages.
- Creates a Shell with a Canvas (in the main thread) and whenever server receives a message, I need to draw a line using the points contained in it.

I've already read some threads about this issue (on updating SWT from another thread) and I've tried to create a method called by my server whenever it receives a message:

```
public static void doPaint(final Canvas canvas, final Draw draw){
        if (canvas != null && draw != null){
            Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                            System.out.println("Printing line....");

                            e.gc.setBackground(e.display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
                            e.gc.setForeground(e.display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));
                            e.gc.setLineWidth(3);                           
                            e.gc.drawLine((int)draw.getStartX(),(int)draw.getEndX(),(int)draw.getStartY(),(int)draw.getEndY());
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
        }
}
```

EDIT

This is the loop that waits for socket messages and triggers the actions:

```
while(isConnected()){
                    try{
                        System.out.println("Waiting for connection...");
                        Socket server = getServerSocket().accept();
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream(), Const.ENC_UTF8));         
                        String inputLine;

                        while(((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)){
                            processInput(inputLine, canvas);                
                        }
                    }catch(IOException ioex){
                        System.out.println(ioex.getMessage());
                        ioex.printStackTrace();
                    }catch (Exception ex) {
                        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

and my `processInput` method is:

```
protected void processInput(String inputLine, Canvas canvas){

        //get draw from input stream
        Draw draw = DrawUtil.getDrawFromInput(inputLine);

        //draw points on live-mode
        BBCanvas.doPaint(canvas, draw);

        //append draw node to XML file
        DrawUtil.writeDrawToFile(draw);
    }
```

... but the runnable in the `doPaint` method is never executed. Any hints?

EDIT 2

This is the code that creates the main shell:

```
public MainWindow(BBServer server) {
        this.server = server;
        Display display = new Display();

        this.mainShell = createShell(display);

        getMainShell().open();

        while (!getMainShell().isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
```

Comment: I expect you would have to do something to cause the canvas to raise a paint event - calling [redraw](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control.html#redraw%28%29) if memory serves.

Comment: Did you try moving the async inside the listener?

Comment: @McDowell I've edit my question and added the 'event' that triggers the paint event.

Comment: @Baz I cannot move the sync/async inside the listener otherwise I get an Exception from SWT cause I'm trying to update a SWT component from another thread.

Comment: Is the main event loop(the readAndDispatch) for SWT running.

Comment: @GorkemErcan yes.. it is. I added the code of the main event. When the user clicks on the "start server" button I open a second shell (with a `canvas` inside) where I need to draw the lines using the points I get through socket.